# Resize event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect window width using a basic function, however, the function isn't updating on resize.

It's basically an email signup form that animates from off canvas on mouse hover.

I don't wish the event to fire when the screen is smaller than 768px.

**CODE**

```
(function ($) {

    var config = {};

    $(document).ready(function () {

        config.window = $(window);

        // Resize
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            resizeWindow();
        }).trigger("resize");

        if ( config.wWidth > 768 ) {
            buildCanvas();
        }

        // EMail Signup
        var $container = $('.email-signup__wrap'),
            $cHeight = $('.email-signup').outerHeight();

        function buildCanvas() {

            $('.email-signup__wrap').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                $container.toggleClass('active');

                if ($container.hasClass('active')) {

                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            overflow: 'visible',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: -$cHeight
                        }
                    });

                } else {

                    TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                        ease: Power2.easeOut,
                        css:{
                            position: 'relative',
                            top: 0
                        },
                        onComplete: hide
                    });

                    function hide(){
                        $container.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    }

                    $("div.mce_inline_error").remove();
                }
            });
        }

        function resizeWindow() {
            config.wWidth = config.window.width();
            config.wHeight = config.window.height();
        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Why would you put the JS Functions within the `$(document).ready()` ? This might be an issue.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle so we can look into your code.

Comment: you can mark me down as much as you please :) this is too urgent to worry. I'll check now Wissam

Comment: Still no joy @WissamEl-Kik

Comment: Put the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/LjiyD    it's rough... but I'm literally minutes away from the deadline @WissamEl-Kik

Comment: The technique I'm using, I've used many times before, so I've no idea why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

This might fix your issue:

```
var window_width = 0;
var window_height = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
        // Calculate the default window width and height
        calculateWindowDimensions();

        // Call the buildCanvas function
        buildCanvas();

        // Calculate the window dimensions on window resize
        $(window).resize(function(){
            calculateWindowDimensions();
            // Call the buildCanvas function
            buildCanvas();
        });
});

function buildCanvas() {
    var $container = $('.email-signup__wrap'),
        $cHeight = $('.email-signup').outerHeight();
    if(window_width > 768){
        // EMail Signup

        $('.email-signup__wrap').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $container.toggleClass('active');
            if ($container.hasClass('active')) {
                TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                    ease: Power2.easeOut,
                    css:{
                        overflow: 'visible',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: -$cHeight
                    }
                });
            } else {
                TweenMax.to($container, .4, {
                    ease: Power2.easeOut,
                    css:{
                        position: 'relative',
                        top: 0
                    },
                    onComplete: hide
                });
                function hide(){
                    $container.css('overflow', 'hidden');
                }
                $("div.mce_inline_error").remove();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // ....
    }
    return false;
}

function calculateWindowDimensions() {
    window_width = $(window).width();
    window_height = $(window).height();
}
```

You need to use `$(document).ready()` or `(function($){`. It doesn't make sense to use both.

Comment: Still no luck. This is crazy... frustrating! Like I say, I've used this technique countless times

Comment: The issue is config.wWidth is not updating on resize

Comment: afraid not... i appreciate your efforts on this

Comment: use `console.log()` to check if the values are correct within the `calculateWindowDimensions()` function and at page load.

Comment: They are within the calculateWindowDimensions() function, however, they don't update outside

Comment: It's impossible because the `window_width` and `window_height` are initiated outside the jQuery(document) function and the other functions.

Comment: You might need to hide `$('.email-signup__wrap')` in the else clause. I didn't understand what's wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myResizeFunction() {
  ...
}

$(function() {
  $(window).resize(myResizeFunction).trigger('resize');
});
```

This will cause your resize handler to trigger on window resize and on document ready. Of course, you can attach your resize handler outside of the document ready handler if you want .trigger('resize') to run on page load instead.

UPDATE: Here's another option if you don't want to make use of any other third-party libraries.

This technique adds a specific class to your target element so you have the advantage of controlling the styling through CSS only (and avoiding inline styling).

It also ensures that the class is only added or removed when the actual threshold point is triggered and not on each and every resize. It will fire at one threshold point only: when the height changes from <= 818 to > 819 or vice versa and not multiple times within each region. It's not concerned with any change in width.

```
function myResizeFunction() {
  var $window = $(this),
      height = Math.ceil($window.height()),
      previousHeight = $window.data('previousHeight');

  if (height !== previousHeight) {
    if (height < 819)
      previousHeight >= 819 && $('.footer').removeClass('hgte819');
    else if (!previousHeight || previousHeight < 819)
      $('.footer').addClass('hgte819');

    $window.data('previousHeight', height);
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).on('resize.optionalNamespace', myResizeFunction).triggerHandler('resize.optionalNamespace');
});
```

As an example, you might have the following as some of your CSS rules:

```
.footer {
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  position: static;
}

.footer.hgte819 {
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good practice checking for screen resolution with JavaScript you have CSS media queries for this.

Any device with a screen width 768px and below will likely be a touch device, which doesn't actually have a hover event, it's a click event.

That being said,

```
if ( config.wWidth > 768 ) {
    buildCanvas();
}
```

This peace of code should be inside a 'resize' function as being standalone the if statement triggers on load only once when the page is loaded. 'On' method doesn't have a 'resize' property, use '.resize()'. Also there is no need in creating a 'resizeWindow' function as you are firing it only once and it does't make your code clearer.

Comment: I'll make your amends and let you know. Thanks for the input

Comment: I understand your point on media queries however I want to stop the javascript for smaller browser windows too. I have a boss where perfection is everything, and me saying it'll be fine on mobile won't fly

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 768px) { #yourCanvasContainer { display: none !important; } }

Comment: I still wish to display the element though, just in a different fashion, and I'd always prefer to avoid repeating elements and using display:none / display:block. I do agree, it's best to use media queries in most situations. The method in my question though is widely used, just I've done something silly in this case and it's broken

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by yourself, try to debug it in chrome or firefox, press **F12**, to start the debugger.
By the way, in chrome/firefox, you can also use following code to print log to console of the debugger:

```
console.log("I am here ...");
```

Comment: You can't be serious with this answer, Eric!... :)